# :dependent => :destroy not working for a model, Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

Rails 3.1.0

I have several models with associations. One of my models keeps erroring out on destroy with a has_many :blocks, :dependent => :destroy with the following error:

```
NoMethodError in BucketsController#destroy

undefined method `delete_all' for #<Array:0x007ffd0cea9bb8>
```

My Bucket model:

```
class Bucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'erb'
  include ERB::Util
  require 'rdiscount'

  has_paper_trail :skip => [:lock_version]

  has_many :blocks, :dependent => :destroy #tried delete_all, nullify, same error
  belongs_to :folder
  belongs_to :pattern
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "updated_by" 
  ...
```

My Block model:

```
class Block < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'erb'
  include ERB::Util
  require 'rdiscount'

  has_paper_trail :skip => [:lock_version]

  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :pattern
  belongs_to :bucket
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "updated_by"
  acts_as_list :scope => :bucket
  ...
```

My Pattern model (works fine)

```
class Pattern < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail :skip => [:lock_version]

  has_many :blocks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :buckets, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "updated_by" 
  ...
```

When I delete a Pattern, it deletes associated blocks or buckets with no problem. I just can't delete a Bucket (and associated blocks) without error. I've tried :delete_all and :nullify with the same error.

Any ideas?

Log

```
Started DELETE "/buckets/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-23 20:16:25 -0700
Processing by BucketsController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"+Bv+RYtusfOYfRkgYwC2Ptaj9brW1412NuVoxe5rD/4=", "id"=>"4"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Bucket Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `buckets`.* FROM `buckets` WHERE `buckets`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 1 AND `roles`.`title` = 'SuperAdmin' LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `buckets`.* FROM `buckets` WHERE `buckets`.`id` =  LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Block Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `blocks`.* FROM `blocks` WHERE `blocks`.`bucket_id` = 4 ORDER BY position, id
 (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 150ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `delete_all' for #<Array:0x007ffd0cea9bb8>):
 app/controllers/buckets_controller.rb:67:in `destroy'
```

Trace

```
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_many.rb:49:in `block in define_delete_all_dependency_method'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:395:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `destroy'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `block in destroy'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.1.0)    lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
...
```

Comment: I also tried to comment out the acts_as_list in the Block model thinking that may have been the problem. No luck.

Comment: also upgraded to 3.1.3 to make sure it wasn't a bug. No luck.

Comment: I figured it out, finally. Will post finding after my 8 hr hold is up.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out after close inspection of the log vs a successful :dependent => :destroy from another model.

```
Block Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `blocks`.* FROM `blocks` WHERE `blocks`.`bucket_id` = 4 
\ORDER BY position, id
```

This line looked like it should be there, but on close inspection the ORDER BY clause didn't belong.

In my Bucket model I had the following for a rake task.

```
def blocks
    Block.where(:bucket_id => self.id).order(:position, :id).all
end
```

This was causing the error. Nothing like spending a few hours on a stupid mistake.